# Site updating after publication

Tags: html, file, web, updates, filezilla

I've just finished to write a site where I'll publish some drawings. I think I'll upload the site on internet during next week but I have a question: in future I'll have to publish new drawings;  How will I publish them in the site? Just uploading files and reloading a new html page with the new code with FileZilla? Thank you in advance!

Comment: If this is a static site then yes you will have to upload drawings and updated HTML page on your server using FTP client (like FileZilla).

Answer (score 0):

> Just uploading files and reloading a new html page with the new code with FileZilla?

Yes that's right, replace the server's old HTML file with your new one using filezilla and then place the new images in the proper place (probably your "images" folder if you created one.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, FileZilla works like that. You can upload a file whenever you want.
Then, on your website, you can reload your page.

So, verify that Filezila is ok for security. One time, I have a security problem with this Tools. Be careful for the password. At my time, this password it was not encrypted !